# probability that the number of roulette spins until the sum of the spins exceeds a given number

Tags: probability

> A roulette wheel is labelled $1$ through $n$, with each number having
> the same probability of being selected and each spin of the roulette is
> independent of the other spins. We spin the roulette until the
> sum of the numbers selected is strictly greater than $n$. Let $S$ be the number of spins it takes for the sum to be strictly greater than $n$. For an integer $m$
> such that $0 \leq m \leq n$, find the probability that $\operatorname{Pr}(S \geq m+1)$?

I understand the continuous version (a sequence $x_j$ is sampled from a uniformly distribution on the interval $[0,1]$ and you continue until the sum is more than 1) has expected value $e$ for the number of samples to get to a sum that exceeds 1. That I understand but in this case, I'm lost on what is multiplied to $(1/n)^m$ (representing the first $m$ roulette spins) as my calculations don't give $e$ as a limit.

How can one obtain an expression for the probability that $S$ is at least $m+1$? In particular, what is multiplied to $(1/n)^m$?

EDIT: Previous problem incorrectly stated $S$ to be the sum of the spins, when it should be the number of spins for the sum to exceed $n$

Comment: I was thinking you could say something like this: $P(S\ge m+1)=1-(S\le m)=1-\bigl[ \frac{1}{m}+(\frac{1}{m^2}+\frac{1}{m})+(\frac{1}{m^3}+2\frac{1}{m^2}+\frac{1}{m})+(\frac{1}{m^4}+3\frac{1}{m^3}+\frac{1}{m^2}+4\frac{1}{m^2}+\frac{1}{m})+... \bigr]$ which doesn't seem to lead to anything i know, the thing that makes sense is that as $m\to +\infty$, $P(S\ge m+1)=1-\frac{1}{m}+o(\frac{1}{m^2})\to 1$ which makes me happy because it makes sense.

Comment: Since $S$ is strictly greater than $n$, we have $S\ge n+1$. Since $m\le n$, this implies $S\ge m+1$. So the probability you are asking for is exactly one. Are you sure you are asking the question you want to ask?

Comment: Oh my bad. I incorrectly misstated what $S$ is, just edited the question to reflect that $S$ is the number of spins

Comment: I'll tell you what I have done, and you tell me if I need to do any more : I have found a constant $K$ explicitly, such that $Pr(S \geq m+1) = K(\frac 1n)^m$. Is this constant $K$ what you needed?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes, how is that constant $K$ found? That's what's I want to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have : $$
P(S \geq m+1) = P(X_1 + ... + X_m \leq n) 
$$

where $X_i$ are iid uniformly distributed in $\{1,2,...,n\}$. Therefore, it is sufficient to find the RHS.

The answer is just $\sum_{1 \leq i_1,...,i_m \leq n} 1_{i_1+...+i_m \leq n} P(X_1 = i_1,X_2 = i_2,...,X_m = i_m)$, which just becomes $\frac {K}{n^m}$, where :
$$
K = |\{(i_1,i_2,...,i_m) \in \{1,2,...,n\}^m : i_1+i_2+...+i_m \leq n\}|
$$

---

We claim that the set given in the definition of $K$ is in bijection with the set $\{(i_1,i_2,...,i_m) \in \{0,1,...,m\}^m : i_1+i_2+...+i_m \leq n-m\}$. The bijection is given by taking a tuple and subtracting $1$ from each entry. It is easy to see, as $n>m$ that the bijection holds.

Now, we *adjoin* an index $i_{m+1} = n-m - (i_1+...+i_m)$, so we get that the above set is in bijection with :
$$
\{(i_1,i_2,...,i_m,i_{m+1}) \in \{0,1,...,m\}^{m+1} : i_1+i_2+...+i_m +i_{m+1} = n-m\}
$$

by projection onto the first $m$ coordinates.

---

This last set is calculated using stars and bars. Indeed, imagine a set of $n$ blanks, each filled with a $|$ or a $\circ$ (ball), so that there are exactly $m$ of $|$ and $n-m$ of $\circ$.
$$
\underbrace{|\circ||\circ\circ\circ|\circ||...|\circ| \circ \circ}_{\text{$n$ blanks}}
$$

The bars separate the circles into $m+1$ parts, each containing $i_1,...,i_{m+1}$ number of circles, which total to $n-m$ circles, and each of which is non-negative. In the example above, $i_1 = 0,i_2 = 1,i_3  =0 , i_4 = 3$ and so on.

It is easy to see that the number of ways of placing these bars and circles is the same as the number of elements in the set mentioned earlier. But we are basically placing $m$ bars into $n$ slots : the answer to this is just $\binom{n}{m}$.

---

Thus, we basically have $K = \binom{n}{m}$, with $Pr(S \geq m+1) = \frac{\binom{n}{m}}{n^m}$.

The expectation of $S$ is equal to $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni n^{-i} = (1 + \frac 1n)^n \to e$ as $n \to \infty$ (i.e. as we approach the uniform distribution)

Comment: What leads to $P(S \geq m+1) = P(X_1 + ... + X_m \leq n)$? I get that the RHS means the probability that the sum of $m$ spins is at most $n$ but I'm missing how it is equal to the probability that the number of spins for the sum to exceed $n$ is at least $m+1$. All the rest I understand.

Comment: @ABBalbuena We know that $S = \inf\{ k : X_1 + ... + X_k > n\}$. Therefore, if $S \geq m+1$ then $m \notin \{k : X_1+...+X_k > n\}$ therefore $X_1+...+X_m \leq n$. Conversely, if $X_1 + ...+X_m \leq n$ then none of $X_1+...+X_k \leq n$ for $k \leq m$ since the sum is monotonically increasing. Therefore, the set $\{k : X_1+...+X_k > n\}$ cannot contain any of $1,...,m$ so its infimum is at least $m+1$ i.e. $S \geq m+1$.

Comment: The rigorous justification for the last paragraph is actually simpler: $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni n^{-i}$ is exactly the binomial theorem expansion of $\left(1 + \frac1n\right)^n$, which goes to $e$.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Thanks for the point out, that was nice. I have edited.